# C# object to Javascript object based on mvc framework

Tags: c#, javascript, javascriptmvc

So I am very new to Javascript and mvc.

I have been working on a backend service to pass back and forth very large objects between a mongodb and a javascript front end interface that will allow a user to populate those objects. The problem is my backend objects are several hundred lines of code long and I don't want to make a mistake copying them over into javascript objects because I am very new to javascript. Is there a way to convert a c# object class to a javascript class in order to create a model for an mvc framework? Is there some part of this structure I don't understand?

Comment: Normally you would use the Json.NET library to serialize a C# class to a JSON string which is what pretty much all JavaScript frameworks expect.  The newer versions of ASP.NET MVC come with Json.NET as the default json serializer so it will use it as long as your client is requesting json.

Comment: I am not looking for a serializer but a way to either automated or lint my model to be sure it is essentially the same object as my c# object

Comment: You can't really "link" server side C# code to client side JavaScript.  You just have to make them talk together.  Serialization is inevitable.  The best thing you can do is to use a JavaScript framework that talks to RESTful web services and implement an ASP.NET Web Api controller for each type of model.  Then you just have to point your JavaScript framework to a URL such as "api/People" and the framework would know how to make read, update, create and delete requests.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Thank you for explaining I was just wondering how I should set up my model for mvc to be able to pass the object to my wcf service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a model server-side, corresponding to your "very large object".
Then, you can pass it to your JS from your controller using :

```
public ActionResult YourMethod(string param1)
{
    //get your object

    return Json(yourObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You can call this method asynchronously from your JS thanks to ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
   url         :   "@Url.Action("YourMethod", "YourController")",
   contentType :   "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType    :   "json",
   type        :   "POST",
   data        :   JSON.stringify({param1: "test"})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [scriptsharp](http://scriptsharp.com/)

It compiles c# to javascript. If you organize your code in a proper way you'll get classes from c# 1:1 in JS.

Comment: I've worked with ScriptSharp in the past, and I will say this: If you aren't already comfortable working in JavaScript, you are going to have problems with Script#. Script# might be a good option if you want a compiler to enforce type safety. But code sharing between server and client is difficult at best, and the community around it is not very big, which makes it hard to troubleshoot problems.

Comment: I agree that support of script# is not best in the world. But just for generating poco's in the right js 'namespace' could do the the trick.